# Catch a Keyboard Interrupt and close the websocket in Python

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, cryptocurrency

I am using the pybitget wrapper by cuongitl and can't figure out how to add a method to catch a Keyboard Interrupt and close the websocket. Currently Ctrl-C get's caught but the websocket continues to run. I have tried to add a catch for Keyboard Interrupt in the main script and also stream.py but it doesn't do anything.

Sorry appreciate this may be a really basic question.

Thanks